# Pydantic autocompletion in VS Code

Tags: python, pydantic

When i use pydantic in VS Code, the code snippet shows `User(**data: Any)`. Is there any way for VS Code to show correct documentation? like `User(name: str, email: str)`

[image]

Comment: See this issue on github: https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1898

Answer (score 2):

As of today, the problem persists, both for pydantic's `BaseModel` classes, as well as the pydantic version of `@dataclass` decorator.

In case of `BaseModel`, add the following piece of code to your imports:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from pydantic import BaseModel


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from dataclasses import dataclass as _basemodel_decorator
else:
    _basemodel_decorator = lambda x: x
```

Then, decorate all classes as follows:

```
@_basemodel_decorator
class MyClass(BaseModel):
    foo: int
    bar: str
```

Alternatively, if you are using pydantic's version of the `dataclass` decorator boilerplate code is simpler:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from dataclasses import dataclass
else:
    from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass
```

Then continue as usual:

```
@dataclass
class MyClass2:
    foo: int
    bar: str
```

Result:
[image: hints for the constructor parameters are showing in VS Code]

More info:

- Credit: https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server/issues/1898#issuecomment-809975087
- On the `TYPE_CHECKING` constant: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've selected a python interpreter, that has pydantic installed.

VS code python extension will give you ability of syntax highlighting, as
well as loading an interpreter.

In right down corner of VS code you will find python interpreter selection
(in my case 3.9.12 version)
[image]

Working example:
[image: Working example]